# Espaciados sin solucion HTM CSS_GRID

Tags: html, css-grid-layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
PADDING DEL HEADER INMENSO

He estado practicando un poco el css grid, pero al realizar este ejemplo, no se de donde ha salido un espacio tan grande en el header y he revisado varias veces en tres navegadores.
Agradezco la ayuda para entender que sucede.

https://github.com/Luchowo/Practica_Grid/tree/Luchowo-patch-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto te esta sucediendo por que en la clase contenedor en el atributo grid-template-rows estas utilizando  unidad fr y este representa una fracción del espacio disponible en el contenedor de la cuadrícula. ... El espacio disponible se divide en cuatro. Y si lo cambias a auto el tamaño de las filas está determinado por el tamaño del contenedor y por el tamaño del contenido de los elementos de la fila. Asi pues que lo unico que debe hacer es:

```
.contenedor {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 75em;
    margin: 1.25em auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.25em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-template-areas:
        'header header header'
        'destacado destacado destacado'
        'contenido contenido aside'
        'footer footer footer';
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias.